# How often do harvesting spots recharge?

Tags: angry-birds-epic

Scattered around the map, I've found a few harvesting spots where I can collect free resources. The tooltip says to "check back often" to see if harvesting is available.

I've found that they don't recharge daily or even at the same time. So how do they recharge? Is it a certain amount of time since they were collected from? Is it a certain number of battles fought? Is it random?

[image: Harvesting spot screenshot]

Comment: Seems somewhat random. The shell (top left corner of your image) recharges pretty much daily. The stump on the starting continent recharges ... I would say around weekly? I have never seen the solid rock recharged yet since I started playing ~1 week ago. The other shell in the eastern sea recharges NOT daily but it does.

Answer (score 1):

From my observations regeration rate is *somewhat* constant, but it's shared across all Harvestings Spots.

In the begining of the game, the two spots I had, were recharged almost every day, but now they recharge also *almost* daily, but it's often hard to find which one has recharged. I would also assume that recharging timer is 'ticking' faster then you play the game.

I also noticed that high-tier spots are recharging more often, then you are high level, so I would assume there are not 'purely' random.

Answer (score 0):

I tried testing this myself by allowing many sites to become charged at once, then harvesting them all. From what I can tell, they recharge basically at random. The earlier sites take a few days, while the later ones take a week or two. The node on the top of the mountain, for example, has only worked three or four times in the few months I've been playing, while the first shell comes up every few days.

My conclusion is that they recharge at some point within a set range, which has higher values for higher nodes. Something like 24-48 hours for early ones, and something like 14-21 days for advanced ones.

Source: A lot of very patient experimentation.